# WPF RichTextBox GetCharacterRect

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

I am trying to get the character rect for all characters typed inside a richtextbox. Starting from the MyRichTextBox.Document.ContentStart textpointer, I advance every character using the following code

```
currentPointer = currentPointer.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward)
```

And retrieve the "character" rect using the following code

```
currentPointer.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward)
```

But it looks like, for any textpointer returned from the piece of code above, the width of the rect is always 0. Now I am able to calculate the character rect based on the area between previous character rect and current character rect, but this causes a problem when a word wrap occurs.

Is there any way I can get a non-zero width from the GetCharacterRect() function of the rich text box ?

EDIT

The content from Microsoft [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textpointer.getcharacterrect%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) shows the same. Is anybody aware of an alternative to measure the character rect ?

Answer (score 2):

`GetCharacterRect` just returns a rectangle representing the leading edge of the character in question (i.e., a zero-width, but accurate height and position) - not a "wrapper rectangle"...although if that's what you are after, you could grab the leading edge of two consecutive characters and do the math.